# Thread do not join if it call tkinter method

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a producer thread and a consumer. I want to display the results of the consumer inside a Tkinter widget. The whole process is started clicking on a button and stopped with another. The produced if not stopped is infinite.

The consumer and the produced threads comunicate with an input queue. The producer put the output in an output queue which is read by a callback thread which fill the Tkinter widget.

Everything works, but the callback thread never join. If I don't fill a tkinter widget, but just print the output it works.

I tried to avoid to fill the tkinter widget by a thread, reading the output queue, but then I am not able to stop the process with the button.

Here a "minimal" example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

import threading
import queue
import time
from threading import Lock


class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Producer, self).__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.input_queue = queue

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while self.running:
            if not self.input_queue.full():
                self.input_queue.put(i)
                i += 1
        return


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, input_queue, output_queue):
        super(Consumer, self).__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.output_queue = output_queue

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            if not self.input_queue.empty():
                item = self.input_queue.get()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                self.output_queue.put(item ** 2)
                self.input_queue.task_done()


class CallBackConsumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, input_queue, callback):
        super(CallBackConsumer, self).__init__()
        self.callback = callback
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.input_queue.empty():
                item = self.input_queue.get()
                self.callback(item)
                self.input_queue.task_done()
            if not self.running and self.input_queue.empty():
                break


class Manager:
    def __init__(self, callback=None, buf_size=10):
        self.input_queue = queue.Queue(buf_size)
        self.output_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.all_producers = []
        self.all_workers = []
        self.callback = callback
        self.callback_worker = None
        self.status = 'stopped'

    def run(self):
        self.status = 'starting'
        p = Producer(self.input_queue)
        p.setDaemon(True)
        self.all_producers.append(p)

        for w in range(5):
            worker = Consumer(self.input_queue, self.output_queue)
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            self.all_workers.append(worker)
            worker.start()

        if self.callback is not None:
            self.callback_worker = CallBackConsumer(self.output_queue, self.callback)
            self.callback_worker.setDaemon(True)
            self.callback_worker.start()

        p.start()
        self.status = 'running'

    def stop(self):
        self.status = 'stopping'
        print('stopping producer')
        for i in range(len(self.all_producers)):
            self.all_producers[i].running = False
            self.all_producers[i].join()

        print('stopping consumer')
        for i in range(len(self.all_workers)):
            self.all_workers[i].running = False
            self.all_workers[i].join()

        if self.callback_worker is not None:
            self.callback_worker.running = False
            print('waiting callback worker to join')
            self.callback_worker.join()

        self.status = 'stopped'
        print('all stopped')


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.task = None

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button_run = tk.Button(self, text="run", command=self.run).pack()
        self.button_stop = tk.Button(self, text="stop", command=self.stop).pack()
        self.log = tk.Text(self)
        self.log.pack()

    def run(self):
        lock = Lock()

        def f(item):
            with lock:
                self.debug(item)

        self.task = Manager(callback=f)
        self.task.run()

    def stop(self):
        self.task.stop()
        self.task = None

    def debug(self, item):
        msg = "%d\n" % item
        self.log.insert(tk.INSERT, msg)  # commenting this line it works
        print(msg)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thread with `daemon` set to True cannot be joined.

Comment: @acw1668: that’s not true, it is possible